# Creating a read only PHP memory stream

Tags: php, stream

I'm looking for a way to implement a read-only **stream** with predefined content inside.

There is an internal `php://memory` stream in PHP. It can be opened in various modes with fopen, one of which is `r` - a read-only stream.

The problem is, there doesn't seem to be a way to initiate it with some content. Obviously, writing to a read-only stream is not supported (I exclude `hhvm` here which seemingly [supports it](https://3v4l.org/jOqeJ) - [by desing](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5187)).

I'm aware of `data://` wrapper. Using it, you can indeed initialise a read-only stream with data inside, although the data needs to be base64/urlencoded which implies some restriction on possible charset. Also, I couldn't really find a documentation on where the data stream is actually stored (in memory or in temp file?).

Comment: Something in the manual about using `data://` wrapper - http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php#100979

Comment: @NigelRen This doesn't answer any questions. Believe me, I've been there.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way of initialising a `php://memory` or `php://temp` stream with data. You also can't open write-only and read-only handles to the same one, as far as I can tell. From a quick test `data://` wrappers are stored in memory, although as you say, they have the restriction that data has to first be base64 encoded. What exactly is your use case? Can you write to a temp file first, then initialise a read-only stream to that?

Comment: The library mikey179/vfsStream might be of use as well - it provides a richer interface for dealing with files kept in memory (importantly, it should allow you to open a read and write handle to the same in-memory file)

Comment: @iainn There is no real-life thing, I was just experimenting with creating a read-only, non-mutable string and memory stream looked like a perfect candidate. I know I can work around that problem using `data://` or `file://` but it's not what I want.

Comment: @iainn I have looked at vfsStream, flysystem and Guzzle streams but none of them is able to estabilish a read-only handle to memory with content. I'm almost sure it cannot be done with memory stream, just wanted to confirm I'm not missing sth obvious.

Comment: https://fossies.org/dox/php-5.6.31-src/memory_8c_source.html
Copy Paste comment from that page:

_Memory streams use a dynamic memory buffer to emulate a stream.
  You can use php_stream_memory_open to create a readonly stream from an existing memory buffer._

So I looked for php_stream_memory_open .. but no time, and it seems its not implemented.